Seeking specific Scientific American form mid 1980s on semiclassical interpretation of Compton Scattering
I seem to recall seeing an article in Scientific American which discussed the possibility of interpreting Compton scattering in terms of classical electromagnetic wave theory.  If anybody is familiar with this article, please identify the issue and title.  I believe the article was printed between 1981 and 1985.

I don't know of that article but there is one from more recently that attempts to do something similar: https://ui.adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/2009APS..TSS.C1003E/abstract (although note that the quantum mechanical nature of light is firmly established in other experiments, even if these arguments are corect)

The closest thing I see in this index is Dec 1985 has an article on stimulated Brillouin scattering. Or Feb 1986 has A Homemade Device for Testing Particle Scattering
